# Как сохранить массив данных для дефолтного описания столбцов js

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

У меня в конструкторе заданы параметры таблицы ag-grid через указатели.
При загрузке страницы я делаю push в новый массив, чтобы держать там дефолтные свойства таблицы.
Но когда я меняю данные функционалом, то мой массив меняется автоматически.

```
let default_storage_head = []; // объявлена глобально за пределами класса

// делаю push данных в пустой массив при загрузке страницы
let context = this;
let myHead = context.dataSetTable.myHeader;
default_storage_head.push(myHead);
```

Далее я допустим меняю заголовки

```
 context.dataSetTable.myHeader.forEach(e=>{
   e.headerName = 'test';
 })
```

Значения моей переменной default_storage_head тоже изменились.
Как мне сохранить изначальный вид массива когда я в первый раз делаю push ?

Comment: Потому что вы пушите в default_storage_head не массив, а ссылку на `context.dataSetTable.myHeader`.

Comment: имеет смысл тогда зайти в context.dataSetTable.myHeader.foreach(e=>{ default_storage_head.push(e);   })
?

Comment: @SwaD, я попытался зайти в context.dataSetTable.myHeader как в массив и сделал push в пустой массив, ситуация осталась той же

Comment: У вас в массиве лежат объекты?

Comment: @SwaD нет, именно массивы

Comment: А внутри вложенных массивов?

Comment: @SwaD да, во вложении есть объекты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим есть массив

```
const a = [[1],[{b: 1, c: [6, 2]}],[3], [{ a: 1}]];
```

Самый простой способ скопировать массив и все его содержимое, если внутри есть простой JSON(без функций):

```
const v = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Если такой способ не подойдет, можно написать кастомное решение примерно такого содержания, что бы на выходе получить новый массив.

```
const b = a.map((d) => {
    return d.map((e) => {
        if (typeof e === 'object' && !Array.isArray(e)) {
            return Object.assign({}, e)
        } if (typeof e === 'object' && Array.isArray(e)) {
            return [ ...e ]
        } else {
            return e;
        }
    })
})
```

Я учел вашу структуру данных(если я все правильно понял). Вы это можете вынести в отдельные функции и клонировать объекты глубже.

Что бы было более понятно, почему так происходит можно почитать тут например про [копирование объектов](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy)

Comment: const v = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)); сработало ! 
это верное решение, хранить данные в объекте. 
Спасибо вам большое !