# Как избавиться от изменения импортируемого массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, который содержится в постороннем файле и экспортируется:

```
export default [{name: "alex", age: 29}, ...];
```

В определенный класс я импортирую его и ставлю в значение переменной:

```
import persons from "./data.js";

class Persons {
  list = persons;
  ...
}
```

Далее в классе есть несколько методов, которые работают с переменной list и изменяют ее.
У меня есть метод, который задает значение переменным по умолчанию:

```
resetToDefault() {
  this.list = persons;
  ...
}
```

Но массив `persons` у меня приходит уже измененный под старый `list` и поэтому `list` не обновляется.
Как избавиться от изменения массива `persons`?

Comment: если не меняете сами элементы, то list = {...person}, иначе так: list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));

Comment: Как вариант сделать "дубль" массива `persons` или сделать json файл, который будет читаться и парсится вместо простого присвоения ссылки.

Comment: Либо можно написать функцию под вашу модель данных, которая будет возвращать новый массив. [Пример функции клонирования массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452047/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2-js/1452079#1452079)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас волнует только то что мутируется массив, но не волнует мутируются ли сами объекты внутри массива, то можно скопировать массив с помощью [синтаксиса spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
list = [...persons];
```

```js
const persons = [
  {
    name: "name 1",
    age: 1
  },
  {
    name: "name 2",
    age: 2
  }
];

class Persons {
  list = [...persons];
  
  mutateList() {
    this.list.map(person => {
      person.name += ' mutated';
      
      return person;
    });
    
    this.list.splice(0, 1);
  }

  resetToDefault() {
    this.list = persons;
  }
}

const personsInstance = new Persons();

console.log('Before mutating :', personsInstance.list);

personsInstance.mutateList();

console.log('After mutating :', personsInstance.list);

personsInstance.resetToDefault();

console.log('After reseting :', personsInstance.list);
```

Если же вам нужно чтобы объекты внутри массива тоже вернулись в прежнее состояние, то можно создать "глубокую" копию массива с помощью комбинации [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) и [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) как это [указано в документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy):

```
list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
```

```js
const persons = [
  {
    name: "name 1",
    age: 1
  },
  {
    name: "name 2",
    age: 2
  }
];

class Persons {
  list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons));
  
  mutateList() {
    this.list.map(person => {
      person.name += ' mutated';
      
      return person;
    });
    
    this.list.splice(0, 1);
  }

  resetToDefault() {
    this.list = persons;
  }
}

const personsInstance = new Persons();

console.log('Before mutating :', personsInstance.list);

personsInstance.mutateList();

console.log('After mutating :', personsInstance.list);

personsInstance.resetToDefault();

console.log('After reseting :', personsInstance.list);
```